# Specify image expiration using CarrierWave and AWS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, carrierwave, fog

Does anyone know how to specify image expiration headers for images uploaded using CarrierWave to AWS through Fog?

I've got this so far:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|  
  config.fog_credentials = {  
    :provider               => #filtered  
    :aws_access_key_id      => #filtered  
    :aws_secret_access_key  => #filtered  
  }  
  config.fog_directory  = #filtered  
end
```

Bonus points for adding this data to a bunch of already uploaded images.

Thank you! I'm a noob, couldn't get this to work on my own.

Comment: Is this question referring to how to generate a secure link to an image that expires after a certain time?  Or a cache expiration?

Comment: cache expiration.
I realized I could pass 'config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}' , but is there anything else I could do. Also, how can I pass that to images already stored on AWS ?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else runs across this, the answer is mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425249#comment-10425962) above:

```
config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{1.year.to_i}" }
```

Or, if using the [carrierwave-aws](https://rubygems.org/gems/carrierwave-aws) gem:

```
config.aws_attributes = { cache_control: 'max-age=604800' }
```

You can use [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) to update the headers on existing objects in s3:

```
s3cmd --recursive modify --add-header="Cache-Control:public, max-age=604800" s3://bucket/path/
```